# How to display images in a listview

Tags: vb.net

I have a couple of images in a imagelist1. I'd like to display images in listview1 control (or something else recommended by someone). Once the image is selected it should display in a picturebox1. I should be able to navigate through (next/previous) pictures and I should also be able to delete pictures.

`ImageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName))` not adding files!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.largeimagelist.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The code isn't completed; you have also to add an Item in your ListView1 control, and after you have to say that this Item has the new Image. Here an example:

```
    Dim newImageKey As String = "<Type here a Key for the image>"
    ImageList1.Images.Add(newImageKey, Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName))
    ListView1.Items.Add("<Your Key Node>", "<Your Text Node>", newImageKey)
```

Comment: Flaick, I've copied your code. Could you please answer my actual question? Can I display images from imagelist1 to listview1?

Comment: Sorry, You have answered my Listview question. Let me try it out.

Comment: Dim newImageKey As String = "10"
        LoginForm.ImageList1.Images.Add(newImageKey, Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName))
        ListView1.Items.Add("1", "Some Image", newImageKey) is this correct?

Comment: The code is correct; but i have a question: LoginForm is an instanced object? If NO your code won't works properly, cause LoginForm didn't keep memory of new image.

Comment: Also don't forget to add code: ListView1.LargeImageList = ImageList1

Comment: I have added a imagelist1 to the local form but still no results on list view neither will it add image to the imagelist1. Please let me know as to how I can make use of the imagelist1 on the Loginform.

Comment: PictureBox1.Image = LoginForm.ImageList1.Images.Item(count) this code displays images to picturebox1 from login form.

Comment: Have you read the link posted above by Tim Schmelter? Is the Microsoft tutorial for ImageList.

Comment: could you please look at my new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880674/loading-and-viewing-images-from-imagelist

Comment: All this while I was adding one image. But when I add two images, the Listview is populated, but with the same image twice.