# Loading and viewing images from imagelist

Tags: vb.net

As you see the code given below is not very useful. Is it possible to shorten the code. Mousewheel back and forward give the same result (next image). Keydown cannot be configured.

```
Private Sub Images_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    count += 1
    If count + 1 > ImageList1.Images.Count Then
        count = 0
    End If
    PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images.Item(count)
End Sub

Private Sub Images_MouseWheel(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseWheel
    count += 1
    If count + 1 > ImageList1.Images.Count Then
        count = 0
    End If
    PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images.Item(count)
End Sub

Private Sub Images_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
        count += 1
        If count + 1 > ImageList1.Images.Count Then
            count = 0
        End If
        PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images.Item(count)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to shorten this, just use function:

```
Private Sub Images_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images.Item(increaseCount(count))
End Sub

Private Sub Images_MouseWheel(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseWheel
If e.Delta > 0 Then
    PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images.Item(decreaseCount(count))
ElseIf e.Delta < 0 Then
    PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images.Item(increaseCount(count))
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Images_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
   PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images.Item(increaseCount(count))
End If
End Sub

Private Function increaseCount(ByRef count as integer) As Integer
    count += 1
    If count + 1 > ImageList1.Images.Count Then
        count = 0
    End If
    Return count
End Sub

Private Function decreaseCount(ByRef count as integer) As Integer
    count -= 1
    If count - 1 > ImageList1.Images.Count OR count < 0 Then
        count = 0
    End If
    Return count
End Sub
```

e.Delta is how much you scrolled, this is depending on the options in the control panel about mouse wheel scrolling. So we can't be sure what these values will be, but the good thing is that scrolling ups is always positive and scrolling down is negative.

Comment: My code looks tidy with the above code. Is there a way for mousewheel(FORWARD) and keyup. I've tried but the images scroll in the same direction as as mousewheel(BACKWARD) and keydown.

Comment: Mouse wheel scrolling works fine. Like how you mentioned, the situation is how much the wheel has been scrolled. At the moment it has to be scrolled slowly. Superb. When you are at the 1st image, scrolling stops. I've added a Try Catch, an error was thrown. Keyup not working. Keydown is working. I may not add a comment since I may be off in a while. Thanks. Once it's done I shall click as answered.

Comment: OK Geek. I've added a sub for KeyUp. It's done. As usual for -1 errrors were thrown. So I've added a Try Catch. Good work. I have another post which I shall disregard and re-post my problem tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: @Farook You should probably switch your answer to this one.  I missed the MouseWheel issue.  BTW, Geek On Demand, +1.

Comment: The problem is when you get to the top most (1st) image the wheel down nor the down key will work. But in between the scrolling is OK. Geek can you work it out?

Comment: You can post a fresh question with some code and we can work for the solution.